# Checked gridview contents in datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, datatable, aspxgridview

I need to store specific column of all the checkbox checked gridview rows  in a datatable on a button click. I tried this code. But nothing is stored in datatable dt and in string variable str..  How to achieve my requirement.. Please help...

```
Protected void btnmail_click(object sender EventArgs e)
{
    datatable dt = new DataTable();
    foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in grd.Rows)
    {
        Checkbox chk = (Checkbox)gvrow.FindControl("chkrow");
        if (chk.Checked == true)
        {
            string str = gvrow.Cells[1].Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you're trying to add a `Row` by using a `string`. You need to add a `DataRow` object. See the example [in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yfsd47w(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet. First you need to create a DataTable and add Columns to it. Then you can add the checked rows to the DataTable.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //create a datatable
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    //add one or more colums to the datatable
    table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Text", typeof(string));

    //loop the gridview rows
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("CheckBox1");

        if (chk.Checked == true)
        {
            string str = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;

            //add a new row to the datatable
            table.Rows.Add(i, str);
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. C# is case sensitive, to `datatable dt` and `Checkbox chk` would never have worked. Are you using an editor such as Visual Studio?

Comment: I tried this. But its not working... variable str remains empty and required value  is not stored in datatable